# Maven Failsafe plugin - SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process (TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy)

Tags: maven, spring-boot, exception, maven-failsafe-plugin

I get this strange stacktrace when running `mvn clean verify -P P1`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.21.0:verify (default) on project prj-name: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\path\to\project\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
```

What does it mean?

Maven pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>P1</id>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <!-- Includes integration tests -->
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/integration/*.java</include>
                                    <include>**/integration/*/*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**UPDATE**

There's a surefire dumpstream file

```
ForkStarter IOException: For input string: "1;5".
org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.MultipleFailureException: For input string: "1;5"
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.<init>(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:58)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer.<init>(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:596)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Because of garbage in string variables and occasional `IndexOutOfBoundsException` / `ConcurrentModificationException` in logs it seems like a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This GitHub issue - [[#6254] Maven-failsafe-plugin fails to execute integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254) - and the related discussion helped me to solve my problem.

It's a bug. It turns out that newer Failsafe plugin versions (2.19.0 and later) don't work well with Spring Boot 1.4 (or later). Workaround is to downgrade the maven-failsafe-plugin to 2.18.1. Here's the updated pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- I don't specify version at all (Spring Boot can autoconfigure plugin version) -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <!-- changed <id> to <phase>, but I don't know whether it's important or not. -->
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <!-- ... no changes here: the same as in the question ... -->
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Essentially, newer versions test against the JAR, whereas until v2.18.1 failsafe uses test-class.

Comment: This config don't run integration test at all. It is not a right answer.

Comment: @burtsevyg, how do you run integration tests? try `mvn verify` command.

Comment: I run `mvn deploy`.

Comment: @burtsevyg `mvn deploy` should work too. try `mvn verify` for comparison and see if it runs your integration tests. Do you follow the naming convention? By default, Failsafe plugin runs test classes named `*/IT.java`, `**/*IT.java`, and `**/*ITCase.java`.

Comment: Thanks , downgrading failsafe from 2.19 to <version>2.18.1</version> helped. [Using spring boot 2.0]

Comment: I've upgraded to version 3.0.0-M5:
<version>3.0.0-M5</version>

Seems to work.

Answer (score 16):

I followed the solution proposed here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254#issuecomment-307151464

Currently, I have failsafe plugin 2.22.0 and I'm able to use this version and not downgrade by explicitly configuring the `classesDirectory` property:

```
<classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
```

Example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
  <configuration>  
     ...                 
     <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
     ...
  </configuration>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <goals>
           <goal>integration-test</goal>
           <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Another variant of the workaround is described later in the same Github issue thread: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254#issuecomment-343470070

```
<classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}.jar.original</classesDirectory>
```

Note (2020-02-27): `maven-failsafe-plugin` version 3.0.0-M4 still needs these workarounds :-(

Answer (score 0):

My testng class was having LoginPageTest.java,  I removed .java and worked  perfectly fine. :)

```
<classes>
  <class name="com.qa.Backend.tests.LoginPageTest"/>
</classes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the problem and mostly the problem is initializing instance variables. Check your instance variables that are working in local and if working check when they are running in CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to configure a classifier for the repackaged jar. This allows Failsafe to use the original jar:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> This problem is due to a combination of a change in the Failsafe plugin and a change in the layout of a repackaged jar file in Boot 1.4. As of Failsafe 2.19, `target/classes` is no longer on the classpath and the project's built jar is used instead. In the case of a Boot app, that's the repackaged jar. In 1.4, the application's classes were moved from the root of the jar to the `BOOT-INF/classes` directory. This prevents them from being loaded by Failsafe.

<sup>src: [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254#issuecomment-229600830)</sup>