# Maven Surefire Plugin Failed to Execute Goal Error

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I tried to execute selenium using maven surefire plugin but i encounter error that i cannot solve it. Below are the erros;

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project Web_Automation: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\peter\IdeaProjects\Web_Automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Mvn clean test command.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
   <configuration>
       <includes>
         <include>Tests.java</include>
        </includes>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Log File:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cimb.Listener.TestListener.onTestFailure(TestListener.java:47)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:96)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:220)
```

It's error point to the first line of onTestFailure method.
Source Code:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.get().fail("Exception: " + result.getThrowable());

        WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("driver");

        String feature = getClass().getName();
        String screenShot;
        try {
            screenShot = CaptureScreenshot.captureScreen(driver, CaptureScreenshot.generateFileName(feature));
            test.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot);
            test.get().log(Status.FAIL, screenShot);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Please help. A billion thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the TestNG problem. Why don't you ask the development team of the TestNG library at the GitHub? https://github.com/cbeust/testng

Answer (score 0):

Configure class directory

```
<configuration>                
     <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
  </configuration>

got from this answer 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363222/maven-failsafe-plugin-surefirebooterforkexception-there-was-an-error-in-the-f][1]
```